# Facebook logout from another activity

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am working on a project. in first activity i am loging with facebook and after logging a new activity launch. where i want to logout from facebook. how to logout from facebook in second activity. plz help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this it worked for me.
// log out from facebook

```
public static void logoutFromFB(Context context) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            // clear your preferences if saved
        }
    } else {
        session = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        // clear your preferences if saved
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
}
Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

Comment: what error you are getting in second activity..from my understanding you need to pass facebook session as parameter to next activity

Comment: how to pass fb session from one activity to another activity? I am using sp and access_token.

Comment: @Amardeep or just create a static variable of facebook session,initialize it with current session in your main activity and clear that session variable from another activity.

Comment: i m create static variable of Facebook. { public static Facebook fb;} in Main Activity. and access this in Another activity on button click . if(MainActivity.fb!=null{try{MainActivity.fb.logout(getApplicationContext());}catch(MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}} This will give me error "FATAL EXCEPTION" and NULLPointerException. what i do. i cant find the solution.

Comment: it seeems that you are using old version of facebook sdk..try with newer version..its much easier

Comment: i am using facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0 and my application min sdk version is 8(2.2). still i am not logout from fb.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
FBLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearApplicationData();
            FBHandler.getInstance(this).facebookLogout();
        }
});   


public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib") && !s.equals("files")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Log.i("TAG",
                            "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s
                                    + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
```

**FBHandler.java**

```
public class FBHandler
{
    private static final String TAG  ="FBHandler";
    private static final String appKey = "your app key";

    private static Facebook facebook = null;

    private static FBHandler _instance = null;

    private static Context context = null;

    private static String[] permissions = null;


    private FBHandler()
    {

    }
    public static FBHandler getInstance(Context ctx)
    {
        if(ctx == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: Context is null, hence returning from the FBHandler");
            return null; 
        }

        context = ctx;
        if(_instance == null)
        {
            facebook = new Facebook(appKey); 
            _instance = new FBHandler();
            permissions = new String[]{"publish_stream","user_photos", "publish_checkins","email","publish_actions"};
        }

        return _instance;
    }


    public void doFbUserLogin(final Activity activity, final fbListner listner)
    {
        if(activity == null || listner == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: User Login activity/Listner is null");
            return;
        }

        facebook.authorize(activity, permissions , new DialogListener()
        {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg(activity, "facebook Login is succeesfull");
                listner.onSuccess();                

            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg(activity, e.getMessage());

            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) 
            {

                printoCommon.showToastMsg(activity, e.getMessage());
            }

            public void onCancel() 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg(activity, "Facebook Login is cancelled");

            }

        });
    }

    public void facebookLogout() 
    {

        AsyncFacebookRunner fbAsyncRun =  new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        fbAsyncRun.logout(context, new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener() 
        {

            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg((Activity) context, e.getMessage());

            }

            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg((Activity) context, e.getMessage());

            }

            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg((Activity) context, e.getMessage());

            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg((Activity) context, e.getMessage());

            }

            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
            {
                printoCommon.showToastMsg((Activity)context, "You have logged out from facebook Successfully");
                ((Activity) context).finish();
            }
        });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

put this **FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());** on your oncreate then write the below code on button click event:

**LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();**

works for me.

took it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31759037/7577192