# How to logout in facebook from another activity?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am using facebook SDK 4.4.0. i want to logout in facebook from another activity?
How can I add logout functionality in another activity ?
I want to go to another activity after successful login and add logout functionality in that activity

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        new fblogin().execute(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    class fblogin extends AsyncTask<AccessToken, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Wait.....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(AccessToken... params) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(params[0],
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.v("MainActivity", response.toString());

                            try {

                                username = object.getString("first_name");
                                emailid = object.getString("email");
                                gender = object.getString("gender");

                                Log.v("User Name", username);
                                Log.v("Email", emailid);
                                Log.v("Gender", gender);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch
                                // block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields",
                    "id,first_name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAndWait();

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First initialize the `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` on your activity then write the below code on button click event:

`LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`

It is done!!!

Comment: FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to hide the visibility of Facebook's Login Button after SignIN.

Then setOnClickListner on normal Button and use this command :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

and a Toast to confirm the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
public static void LogoutFB(Context context) {
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null) {

    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        //clear your preferences if saved
    }
} else {

    session = new Session(context);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);

    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        //clear your preferences if saved
}

}
```

Comment: Is it working for facebook sdk 4.4.0??Have you tried ?

Comment: Since Facebook's Android SDK v4.0 you need to execute the following:

LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();